# How can I trigger some steps and skip when spesific files or folder changed on github actions?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, pipeline

I try to create a pipeline with if conditions.

When I try to change a file or folder in foo2 or foo folder, some tests should be skipped. But all steps are running instead of skipping some tests. Because I only changed files in a folder. Not both of them.

I'm using this action for paths changes filter: [dorny/paths-filter@v2](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/paths-changes-filter)

For example '# minify files for each project' part in the YAML file is not working properly. When I change just one folder, all steps of that part are working. But it should not.

My File directory is like this:

- github

  - workflows

    - main.yml
- foo

  - js

    .bc-global.js

    - live

      .global-bundle.js

      .script-bundle.js
    - scripts

      .script1.js

      .script2.js

      .script3.js

***Foo2 folder's directory same as the foo folder.***

This is my YAML file:

```
name: Upload to S3

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test-s3
    paths:
      - "foo/js/bc-global.js"
      - "foo/js/scripts/**.js"
      - "foo2/js/lc-global.js"
      - "foo2/js/scripts/**.js"

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
        id: changes
        with:
          filters: |
            foo:
              - 'foo/js/bc-global.js'
              - 'foo/js/scripts/**.js'
            foo2:
              - 'foo2/js/lc-global.js'
              - 'foo2/js/scripts/**.js'

      - name: Install node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.13.0
          registry-url: "https://registry.npmjs.org"

      - name: Install uglify-js
        run: npm install uglify-js -g

      # minify files for each project
      - name: minify script files for foo
        if: steps.changes.outputs.foo == 'true'
        run: uglifyjs foo/js/scripts/**.js -o foo/js/live/scripts-bundle.js
      - name: minify global file for foo
        if: steps.changes.outputs.foo == 'true'
        run: uglifyjs foo/js/bc-global.js -o foo/js/live/global-bundle.js

      - name: minify script files for foo2
        if: steps.changes.outputs.foo2 == 'true'
        run: uglifyjs foo2/js/scripts/**.js -o foo2/js/live/scripts-bundle.js
      - name: minify global file for foo2
        if: steps.changes.outputs.foo2 == 'true'
        run: uglifyjs foo2/js/lc-global.js -o foo2/js/live/global-bundle.js

      # Auto committing
      - name: Auto committing minified files
        uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
        with:
          file_pattern: "*.js"
          commit_message: "Github Action: Auto Minified JS files"
          branch: ${{ github.ref }}

      # Deploy for foo
      - name: Deploy to S3 for foo
        if: steps.changes.outputs.foo == 'true'
        uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
        with:
          args: --follow-symlinks --cache-control max-age=600
        env:
          AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_BUCKET_NAME }}
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
          SOURCE_DIR: "foo/js/live"
          DEST_DIR: "foo/pages/assets/js/test/"

        # Deploy for foo2
      - name: Deploy to S3 for foo2
        if: steps.changes.outputs.foo2 == 'true'
        uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
        with:
          args: --follow-symlinks --cache-control max-age=600
        env:
          AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_BUCKET_NAME }}
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
          SOURCE_DIR: "foo2/js/live"
          DEST_DIR: "foo2/pages/assets/js/test/"
```

Comment: The implementation looks fine to me. Did you try printing `steps.changes.outputs.foo` and `steps.changes.outputs.foo2` before using them to check if the values were the expected ones?

Comment: Yes exactly. Looks fine to me as well. How can I check them? I don't get it. Like a console.log check? Also, I tried to change each of them to false. It skips steps when I changed them to false. It's really weird. @GuiFalourd

Comment: You can simply do something like `run: echo ${{ steps.changes.outputs.foo }}` (idem for `foo2`) in your workflow after the `changes` step.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried it. It gives true for everything, really weird. I created an issue on github for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved. I added this line(base) above the filters section:

```
    with:
      base: ${{ github.ref }}
      filters: |
        foo:
          - 'foo/js/bc-global.js'
          - 'foo/js/scripts/**.js'
        foo2:
          - 'foo2/js/lc-global.js'
          - 'foo2/js/scripts/**.js'
```